# Google Sheets API send multiple data in one requisition

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How to send multiple data in just one request to the sheets API?

Example:

I am currently querying a database, and each row returned sends a request to update the data in the Google Sheet.

Here's the code:

```
// Consulta Desvios TL8
        ResultSet DesviosTL8 = stm.executeQuery("QUERY_STRING");

        int DiaDsvAnt = 0;
        int celulaInicial = 10;
        while (DesviosTL8.next()) {
            int DiaDsv = DesviosTL8.getInt(2);
            int valorDsv = DesviosTL8.getInt(1);

            System.out.print("\n" + DiaDsv + " Dia Anterior: " + DiaDsvAnt + " Valor " + valorDsv);


                celulaRealizado = "GRÁFICO PRODUÇÃO!L" + celulaInicial;

                List<List<Object>> valor = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Object> valorLista = new ArrayList<>();
                valorLista.add(valorDsv);
                valor.add(valorLista);
                // Insiro na Planilha
                ValueRange valorTurno1DiaAtual = new ValueRange().setValues(valor).setMajorDimension("ROWS");
                serviço.spreadsheets().values().update(IdPlanilha, celulaRealizado, valorTurno1DiaAtual)
                        .setValueInputOption("RAW").execute();

                // Somo +1
                celulaInicial = celulaInicial + 1;



            }

            DiaDsvAnt = DiaDsv;
        }
```

I would like instead of sending the request to each loop, that the request be sent only at the end of the results.

Example

Query returned 10 rows
Then it will send a request with all the data to fill the cells

GRÁFICO PRODUÇÃO!L10
Up to Cell 
GRÁFICO PRODUÇÃO!L20

Comment: Use `serviço.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate` outside your `while` loop. JavaDoc here: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/ and HTTP REST description here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate

Comment: @tehhowch nice, thankyou!!